# Get parent of class of instance

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class POCOConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<POCO>
{
    public POCOConfiguration()
    {

    }
}
```

```cs
POCOConfiguration instance = new POCOConfiguration();
```

How can I get the type `POCO` from the **instance**?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
instance.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is simply that `instance.GetType().BaseType` returns the base Type of class o parent class.

`instance.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0]` can throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx

There is an example that shows how to get the type (Steps 3,4 and 5)

Answer (score 0):

If the class has a paremeterless constructor, then you can write:

```
public class POCOConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<POCO> where POCO : new()
{     
    public POCOConfiguration()
    {
        var poco = new POCO();
    } 
}
```

Otherwise you have to use reflection, see [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Activator.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
POCOConfiguration instance = new POCOConfiguration();
Type t = instance.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
//here t is the type of POCO
```

will work...

Comment: If you're specifically testing for the POCO type like this, then it's much easier to do `if (instance is EntityTypeConfiguration<POCO>) { }` rather than use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want to get the type of POCO. Then declare a method and call it like the following;

```
public Type GetTypeOfPoco<T>(EntityTypeConfiguration<T> entityTypeConfiguration)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    return t;
}
```

call it;

```
Type t = GetTypeOfPoco(instance);
```